# JAXB generic @XmlValue

Tags: java, xml, generics, jaxb, marshalling

The goal is to produce the following XML with [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_interfaces.html)

```
<foo>
   <bar>string data</bar>
   <bar>binary data</bar>
</foo>
```

Is there a workaround to allow **generic** [`@XmlValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlValue.html) fields (I need to store `byte[]` and `String` data)? Below is what I desire:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {
    private @XmlElement List<Bar> bars;
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Bar<T> {
    private @XmlValue T value;  // (*)
}
```

But I get this exception

> (*) IllegalAnnotationException:
>   @XmlAttribute/@XmlValue need to reference a Java type that maps to text in XML.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could leverage an `XmlAdapter` for this use case instead of `@XmlValue`:

**BarAdapter**

```
package forum8807296;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class BarAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object, Bar<?>> {

    @Override
    public Bar<?> unmarshal(Object v) throws Exception {
        if(null == v) {
            return null;
        }
        Bar<Object> bar = new Bar<Object>();
        bar.setValue(v);
        return bar;
    }

    @Override
    public Object marshal(Bar<?> v) throws Exception {
        if(null == v) {
            return null;
        }
        return v.getValue();
    }

}
```

**Foo**

The `XmlAdapter` is associated with the `bars` property using the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation:

```
package forum8807296;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {
    private List<Bar> bars;

    @XmlElement(name="bar")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BarAdapter.class)
    public List<Bar> getBars() {
        return bars;
    }

    public void setBars(List<Bar> bars) {
        this.bars = bars;
    }

}
```

**Bar**

```
package forum8807296;

public class Bar<T> {
    private T value;

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

**Demo**

You can test this example using the following demo code:

```
package forum8807296;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<Bar>();
        foo.setBars(bars);

        Bar<String> stringBar = new Bar<String>();
        stringBar.setValue("string data");
        bars.add(stringBar);

        Bar<byte[]> binaryBar = new Bar<byte[]>();
        binaryBar.setValue("binary data".getBytes());
        bars.add(binaryBar);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Note how the output includes the `xsi:type` attributes to preserve the type of the value.  You can eliminate the the `xsi:type` attribute by having your `XmlAdapter` return `String` instead of `Object`, if you do this you will need handle the conversion from `String` to the appropriate type yourself for the unmarshal operation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo>
    <bar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">string data</bars>
    <bar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:base64Binary">YmluYXJ5IGRhdGE=</bars>
</foo>
```

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't get `@XmlValue` working as I always got `NullPointerException` along the way—not sure why. I came up with something like the following instead.

Drop your `Bar` class entirely, because, as you want it to be able to contain *anything* you can simply represent it with `Object`.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo", namespace = "http://test.com")
@XmlType(name = "Foo", namespace = "http://test.com")
public class Foo {

  @XmlElement(name = "bar")
  public List<Object> bars = new ArrayList<>();

  public Foo() {}
}
```

Without telling JAXB which namespaces your types are using every `bar` element inside a `foo` would contain separate namespace declarations and stuff—the `package-info.java` and all the namespace stuff serves only *fancification* purposes only.

```
@XmlSchema(attributeFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
           elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
           namespace = "http://test.com",
           xmlns = {
               @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://test.com", prefix = ""),
               @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", prefix = "xsi"),
               @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", prefix = "xs")})
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Running this simple test would spout-out something similar to your XML snippet.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
  JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

  Foo foo = new Foo();
  foo.bars.add("a");
  foo.bars.add("b".getBytes());

  Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
  marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
  marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://test.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <bar xsi:type="xs:string">a</bar>
    <bar xsi:type="xs:base64Binary">Yg==</bar>
</foo>
```

Comment: +1 - Here is an example of how you could use an `XmlAdapter` to do the same thing, but keep the `Bar` class:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8901997/383861

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't simply construct a String with your byte[]? Do you truly need a generic?

Comment: That would require me to convert opaque binary data to a String, e.g., I must manually encode it into e.g., hexBinary or base64.  But yes, that's what I'm currently using as a workaround.

Comment: Are you using your own encoding algorithm? It should be pretty painless if you use the [apache commons encoder](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html).

Comment: I'm using the [HexBinaryAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/HexBinaryAdapter.html) which alt. commons base64 class, both which are nice one-liners.

Answer (score 0):

The trick I'm usually using is to create schema with types you want and then use xjc to generate Java classes and see how annotations are used. :) I believe in XML schema proper type mapping for byte[] is 'base64Binary', so creating schema like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <element name="aTest" type="base64Binary"></element>
</schema>
```

and running xjc we would get following code generated:

```
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema", name = "aTest")
public JAXBElement<byte[]> createATest(byte[] value) {
    return new JAXBElement<byte[]>(_ATest_QNAME, byte[].class, null, ((byte[]) value));
}
```